# How can i clear my input fields after submiting a form?

Tags: reactjs

I have a contact form and i want to clear the input fields and textarea after my submit function is triggered. How can i achieve this by managing the states?

This is my Form component: Where the initial state of my inputs are empty strings and the input change i set that value to the setFormValues which i set later to empty strings again after the form is submitted.

```
import React, { forwardRef, useState } from 'react'
import Input from '../atoms/Input'

const Form = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({ user_name: '', user_mail: '', message: '' });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onSubmit(formValues);
    setFormValues({ user_name: '', user_mail: '', message: '' });
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <form ref={ref} onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="contact-form reveal">
            <h3>Send Message</h3>
            <Input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Name" value={formValues.user_name} onChange={handleChange}/>
            <Input type="text" name="user_mail" placeholder="Email" value={formValues.user_email} onChange={handleChange}/>
            <div className="input-box">
                <textarea  id="" cols="30" rows="10"  name="message" placeholder="Message" value={formValues.message} onChange={handleChange}></textarea>
            </div>
            <div className="input-box">
                <input type="submit" className="send-btn" value="Send"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
})

export default Form
```

This is my Contact component:

```
import './Contact.css'
import { FiMail, FiPhone } from 'react-icons/fi'
import { MdLocationPin } from 'react-icons/md'
import ContactCard from '../molecules/ContactCard';
import ContactTitle from '../molecules/ContactTitle';
import Form from '../organisms/Form';
import Section from './Section';
import useEmailSender from '../hooks/UseEmailSender';
function Contact() {

  const [formRef, sendEmail] = useEmailSender();

  return (
    <div className='main-container'>
        <Section className="contact reveal" id="contact">
        <ContactTitle title="Contact Me" />
        <div className="content">
            <div className="row">
              <ContactCard title="Address" content="Tigre, Buenos Aires, Argentina" icon={<MdLocationPin/>}/>
              <ContactCard title="Phone" content="+5491136176018" icon={<FiPhone/>}/>
              <ContactCard title="Email Address" content="ghidinimateo1@gmail.com" icon={<FiMail/>}/>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <Form ref={formRef} onSubmit={sendEmail} />
            </div>
        </div>

    </Section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Contact
```

This is my useEmailSender.js custom hook:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

function useEmailSender() {
  const formRef = useRef();

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('####', '######', formRef.current, '#########')
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error.text);
      });
  };

  return [formRef, sendEmail];
}

export default useEmailSender;
```

But i get the following errors:

> Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
> textarea

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What do you mean why? I have a custom hook where i integrated an API to send an email with the information the user inputs in the contact form. When the form is sent i want to clear the fields @NathanielFlick

Comment: Is this even related to my question? @easleyfixed

Comment: There's no need to clear the form after submit.@tukitooo1998

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be the issue:

`<input type="submit" className="send-btn" value="Send"/>`

I would drop `value` entirely and just use `button` wrapping "Send":

`<button type="submit" className="send-btn">Send</button>`

Comment: This gives me the error e.prevenDefault() is not a function.

Comment: That's probably due to your `useEmailSender` hook which is responsible for the `formRef` that gets forwarded to `Form`. What does `useEmailSender` look like?

Comment: i have edited my question an added the useEmailSender block o code.

Comment: Why are you passing `formRef.current` with the `sendForm` call?

Comment: Because of the API docs `https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/` where formRef.current is a reference to the form that is being send with all the input data.

Comment: Inside `sendEmail`, if you `console.log(e)`, what are the results? Also is `console.log(formRef.current)` outputting the form reference? Your ref forwarding seems fine.

Comment: `console.log(e)` seems okey to me returns the following:
`Object { _reactName: "onSubmit", _targetInst: null, type: "submit", nativeEvent: submit, target: form.contact-form.reveal` In the Form.js but the `console.log(e)` in the useEmailSender returns `e.preventDefault is not a function`.
Another issue i found is that `console.log(formRef.current)` returns an empty string for `user_email` and `user_name` but not for `message`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it is too late. By the way, I resolved the problem like following:

```
const sendEmail = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

emailjs.sendForm('####', '######', formRef.current, '#########')
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.text);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error.text);
  });
  e.target.reset; //it resets the form
};
```